# Exception raised while including google map to my android application

Tags: android, google-maps

I installed google play services in my sdk. 
My xml file is attached below

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

But an exception is raised after compiling java file.
Complete Log file also attached.

```
08-05 06:02:06.686: D/AndroidRuntime(1236): Shutting down VM
08-05 06:02:06.686: W/dalvikvm(1236): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.viewindia/com.example.viewindia.ViewIndia}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class fragment
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class fragment
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     at com.example.viewindia.ViewIndia.onCreate(ViewIndia.java:25)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     ... 11 more
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:592)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4738)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     ... 21 more
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.viewindia-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.viewindia-2, /system/lib]]
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
08-05 06:02:06.847: E/AndroidRuntime(1236):     ... 24 more
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You linked Google Play Services with your project as a library?

Comment: No, how can I link it?

Comment: use this link http://venkoolit.blogspot.in/2013/05/tutorial-for-develop-google-maps-in-api.html

Comment: @maria have you enabled Google Android Map v2 in google APi console??

Comment: @Venki your blog is very useful

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the Google Play Service SDK as a project in your workspace (assuming you're using Eclipse). This is described [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Install).

The next step is to link this project with your Android project as a library. Here's the [docu](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject) about this step.